# Wanting to use only one email

Tags: applications, email

I have to use 2 emails on my phone at all times cause some apps I purchased on one email and some I got on my other email. Is there a way to put all my purchases on to my primary email so that I don't have to use 2 emails forever?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way of doing it. You can download apps again to the same userid account on different devices, but you cannot transfer those licenses to other userids. So you'll have to rebuy the apps on one account which you wish to keep if you want to stop using both accounts.

Comment: Im digging further into the matter and contacting Google.

Comment: alright best of luck